# difference between background-img into div and image in laravel 6

Tags: laravel, url, slider, assets, src

i have a little problem in laravel 6, when i past this first code of the div

```
<div style="background-image: url({{ asset('storage/'.$slider->cover_img) }})">
```

it doesnt show, like its skipping one \ in the image link

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$product->cover_img) }}" alt="Product image">
```

and when i past the img code it works, but i need it inside the div, i think the issue is due to the difference between src and url...

For the console problem, it skipps one \ and marge the name of the folder with the name of the image

Answer (score 0):

try this

as `url()` is css function so you need to pass value `{!! $value !!}` may be it will work please check

```php
<div style="background-image: url({!! asset('storage/'.$slider->cover_img) !!})">
```

Comment: Still the same problem ( slidersMarch2020%0Fk658clSBo67KfNtS02C.jpg:1 Failed to load resource ) ... He just merged the sliders folder with the March2020 folder and with the picture, with no slash \ or /